# Is there an elegant way to block a bunch of referrers at once?

Tags: nginx

In order to prevent referrer spam, my nginx.conf contains a section like this:

```
if ($http_referer ~* spamdomain1\.com) {
    return 444;
}
if ($http_referer ~* spamdomain2\.com) {
    return 444;
}
if ($http_referer ~* spamdomain3\.com) {
    return 444;
}
```

These rules tell nginx just to close the connection if the user has one of these referrers set. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Can I define a list of these domains and then say something like, “If the referrer is in this list then return 444”?

Comment: create one big file quite like the one from sample and use it as include file where needed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would try a [`map`](http://nginx.org/r/map):

```
map $http_referer $bad_referer {
    default                  0;
    "~spamdomain1.com"       1;
    "~spamdomain2.com"       1;
    "~spamdomain3.com"       1;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
if ($bad_referer) {
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: Since map uses a hash tables this approach will perform better than a series of individual checks. Read the docs for options that could be used, like `hostnames` and possiblely `include` of a separate file where they are listed could make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Reading the docs related to `map` I was interested to see if one could use regex to match certain referrers since OP is doing regex matching using `~*` operator, and indeed simply specifying map rule like `"~*spamdomain4.com" 1;` will do the trick. Neat!

Comment: You're right, and this needs to use it anyway.

Comment: Using the `hostnames` option it would be simply `.spamdomain4.com 1;`

Comment: @Brian The referer field is a complete URL, not simply a hostname. So that doesn't work.

Comment: @Micheal Hampton I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I had to play around with where each block goes in nginx configs, so here it is for clarity. Put `map` into `http {}` and the `if` statement into `location {}`.

Answer (score 14):

You could use logical `OR` to craft one multi match statement e.g.

```
if ($http_referer ~ "spamdomain1\.com|spamdomain2\.com|spamdomain3\.com")  { 
  return 444;
}
```

**EDIT** per comment; removing `break;` from the block

Comment: The break directive will never be reached as return stops the processing of the current request.

Answer (score 3):

[ngx_http_referer_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html) is another way to do it. Example from [Referer Spam Blocking](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/refererspam/):

```
location / {
  valid_referers none blocked *.badreferer1.com badreferer2.com *.badreferer3.com badreferer4.net;

  if ($invalid_referer) {
    return   403;
  }
}
```